# Requested value '1px' was not found. PDF Sharp. Is this a format error?

Tags: c#, html, css, pdf-generation, pdfsharp

I have successfully generated a PDF using PDF Sharp, but it throws a few exceptions and the style is off.

I need some help interrupting this exception.

```
    Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll

    Additional information: Requested value '1px' was not found.
```

No where in my .css or my html guide do I reference '1px', but I do reference '1pt'. Are they the same thing?

It also throws an exception regarding the (tag?) inset, but I do not reference this either.

Have I set up the library incorrectly, or does it not support these items?

Comment: Your question is not about PDFsharp - PDFsharp does not handle HTML or CSS. What this question is about is rather unclear. Show more code, list the libraries you are using, give a complete stack trace for the exception, ...

Comment: Sorry, your right, that was unclear. I was using a library based on pdfsharp https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp/

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this issue with Visual Studio Debugging.
Generally the application runs with out throwing this error.
You can tell Visual Studio to ignore and everything works as expected.

It still does it with versions 2019 Visual Studio and version 1.5.1.0 of HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp as of 2020-10-29